# Is energy always measured in units of mass × length$^2$/time$^2$ in physics?

Tags: energy, units, dimensional-analysis, si-units

Is it always $ M\,L^2/T^2$?

Is special relativity different from general relativity regarding the units of energy?

Comment: These seem to be two rather distinct questions you've asked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're asking about the dimensions of the famed $E=mc^2$. The answer to your question is yes, energy is always measured (at least in SI units) in Joules, or "kilogram meters squared per second squared" (compare the relativistic formula to that for kinetic energy, $mv^2/2$, or for work, $\int F\cdot\mathrm{d}x$, hich all have the same units). It'd be rather silly if special relativity defined energy to have different units than used in classical Newtonian physics.

If you have any more specific questions, please comment below.

I hope this helps!

Comment: So there is no 4D spacetime where one does not split up the location into three space coordinates and one time coordinate?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "splitting up the location into three space coordinates and one time coordinate." Relativity treats space and time on essentially equal footing. The only difference between them is encoded in the metric (which essentially defines the way you take dot products between 4-vectors).

Comment: @Bob it's best not to have people ask separate questions in the comments. Asking for clarification on an answer is a fine use of comments, but other than that, most followup questions should be new, independent posts. Accordingly, could you edit out the next-to-last line?

Answer (score 1):

I'll ignore your second question.

As to the first: superficially, no.

In electrostatics, for instance, the energy stored in a charged capacitor is E = CV^2/2 (capacitance times voltage squared over two).

However, if you dig into the definition of voltage and capacitance, you'll find that ultimately it all falls back to the standard definition.

You'll also find similar unit correspondences in all sorts of branches of physics. In material science, for instance, you'll find strain energy, which is volume times stress squared, divided by 2 time Young's Modulus. Looking into these quantities will also lead you right back to your original units.

Answer (score -4):

Yes of course because 
Energy=power×time=w/t×t=w
Work=w,t=time
Work=force×displacemnt=m×a×l
m×L×L/T²

Comment: Please, use proper spelling and give clear answers. Remember that they should stay here forever.